# How to add padding to a widget, but not the entire row's widgets, in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have an large frame of a wide array of elements. Within this frame, there are basically two different sides to the frame. Consider a widget `x` on the left side, which is placed by `.grid(row=4, column=0)`. Padding is added to this object `x`, so it is actually `x.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10)` Well, the opposite object, object `y`, is placed on the same row by `y.grid(row=4, column=4)`, or something along those lines. I have this setup, but the *pady* on *x* is adding padding to `y` as well. **I want there to be padding on one widget in the row-- not the entire row.** Therefore, my paraphrased question is, *how does one add padding to only one widget in a row, without adding padding to every object in that respective row?*

Comment: `pady = 10` is adds 10 pixels on the top and bottom of x.  When the wigdets in the row are gridded, the row will have the height of the tallest item in the row, including its padding.  If you're getting more padding than you want, try reducing the amount to padding.   (You could also try using `ipady = 10` instead; I've never really understood what the difference is supposed to be.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `.grid()` geometry manager, the maximum size of a widget including it's spacing will be the width and length of the entire row and column.  Thankfully, there are ways to work around this.  Here are two such options:

***Option 1***

Use a sticky to force your widget `y` to the right place.  It will look something like this:  `y.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nw")`.  The "nw" is where the widget will stick in it's spot on the grid.  If you, for example, set it to "n", `y` will be positioned at the top of its grid-space.

***Option 2***

Use `columnspan` or `rowspan` to allow widget `x` to occupy more than one grid space.  This looks like `x.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=2)`.  This will stretch `x`'s grid space and won't effect widgets to it's right and left sides.  Think of it as this; `row` is where you start drawing a rectangle and `columnspan` or `rowspan` is where you end.

With these ideas in mind, take a look at [this link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) to see how the methods I described above work.

Comment: This was an incredible, non-condescending explanation. Thank you very much, @Camon.

Answer (score 0):

The very definition of a row is that is the same height all the way across. That's what makes it a row. The same can be said for columns.

Therefore, the tallest item in a row (height plus padding) is what controls the overall height of the row. The only control you have over smaller widgets is which sides of their too-large cell they stick to.

For example, if you want all widgets to be aligned along their tops, use `sticky="n"`, which causes the top of the widgets to "stick" to the top (north) side of the space they have been allocated. If you want them aligned along their bottoms, use `sticky="s"`. Providing neither `"n"` or `"s"` means they will be aligned along their midpoints.